# How can I print the values of Keras tensors?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensor

I am implementing own Keras loss function. How can I access tensor values?

What I've tried

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    print y_true
```

It prints

```
Tensor("target:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
```

Is there any Keras function to access `y_true` values?

Comment: How can you print its value?  I did that and nothing comes out.  Using Tensorflow backend.

Answer (score 34):

Keras' backend has `print_tensor` which enables you to do this. You can use it this way:

```
import keras.backend as K

def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.print_tensor(y_true, message='y_true = ')
    y_pred = K.print_tensor(y_pred, message='y_pred = ')
    ...
```

The function returns an identical tensor. When that tensor is evaluated, it will print its content, preceded by `message`.
From the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/backend/#print_tensor):

> Note that print_tensor returns a new tensor identical to x which should be used in the following code. Otherwise the print operation is not taken into account during evaluation.

So, make sure to use the tensor afterwards.

Comment: This looks great, but longer tensors are not printed whole (like this: softmax = [[0.0599291697 0.0380649045 0.0828271]...]). Do you know a way to print them whole (or at least control how long they are printed?)

Comment: @Pablo I could not find any reference to this functionality. Using tensorflow backend, the implementation of [`print_tensor`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/ebdc1c8759f65768212b7e7113b5cae82e9df3d4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2450) uses [`tf.Print`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/logging_ops.py#L41), which receives the `summarize` parameter that could provide this functionality, but Keras' `print_tensor` does not forward that parameter. You could try manually adding the `summarize` parameter to `print_tensor`.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the only way (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10566)

Answer (score 5):

Usually, `y_true` you know in advance - during preparation of your train corpora...

However, there's one trick to see the values inside `y_true` and/or `y_pred`. Keras gives you an opportunity to write respective [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/) for printing the neural network's output.
It will look something like this:

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_true # or y_pred
...
import keras.callbacks as cbks
class CustomMetrics(cbks.Callback):

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        for k in logs:
            if k.endswith('loss_fn'):
               print logs[k]
```

Here the `loss_fn` is name of your loss function when you pass it into the `model.compile(...,metrics=[loss_fn],)` function during model's compilation.

So, finally, you have to pass this `CustomMetrics` callback as the argument into the `model.fit()`:

```
model.fit(x=train_X, y=train_Y, ... , callbacks=[CustomMetrics()])
```

P.S.: If you use Theano (or TensorFlow) like here in Keras, you write a python program, and then you compile it and execute. So, in your example `y_true` - is just a tensor variable which is used for further compilation and loss function counting.

It means that there's no way to see the values inside it. In Theano, for example, you can look inside the only so-called shared variable after the execution of respective `eval()` function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361377/how-to-get-value-from-a-theano-tensor-variable-backed-by-a-shared-variable) for more info.

Comment: With your code, it gives this error:   "AttributeError: 'ProgbarLogger' object has no attribute 'log_values'
"

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TensorFlow's keras, you can enable [Eager Execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager):

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```

Afterwards you can print the tensors in your loss function.

In case you get the error message "ValueError: Only TF native optimizers are supported in Eager mode." and you have used 'adam' as an optimizer for example, you can change the model's compile arguments to

```
model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss = loss_fn, ...)
```

**Update: TensorFlow 2.x**

You only need to enable the "run_eagerly" parameter for Eager Execution of Keras models, as stated in [Keras debugging tip 3](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/debugging_tips/#tip-3-to-debug-what-happens-during-fit-use-runeagerlytrue):

```
model.compile(..., run_eagerly = True)
```

Afterwards you can output the tensor in your custom loss function using `print(y_true)`, `tf.print(y_true)` or `K.print_tensor(y_true)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. None of `print()`, `tf.print()`, `K.print_tensor` inside the loss function worked

Comment: @Rylan: I've updated my answer for TensorFlow 2. Hope it works there for you!

Answer (score 3):

You could redefine your loss function to return the value instead:

```py
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_true
```

Let's create some tensors:

```py
from keras import backend as K

a = K.constant([1,2,3])
b = K.constant([4,5,6])
```

And use the [`keras.backend.eval()`](https://keras.io/backend/#eval) API to evaluate your loss function:

```py
loss = loss_fn(a,b)
K.eval(loss)
# array([1., 2., 3.], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

to print the value of a tensor you need the tensor to have value
for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

aa = tf.constant([1,5,3])
bb = keras.layers.Dense(4, name="my_tensor")
print('aa:',aa)
print('bb:',bb)


aa: tf.Tensor([1 5 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
bb: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x000001D4B0137048>
```

if i want to print b I need to give him a input
like this:

```
aa = tf.constant([[1,5,3]])
bb = keras.layers.Dense(4, name="my_tensor")
print('bb.weights before a assign:',bb.weights,'\n')
print('bb:',bb(aa),'\n')                               
print('bb.weights:',bb.weights)
```

Output:

```
bb.weight before a assign: [] 

bb: tf.Tensor([[1.0374807 3.4536252 1.5064619 2.1762671]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32) 

bb.weight: [<tf.Variable 'my_tensor/kernel:0' shape=(3, 4) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.885918  , -0.88332534, -0.40944284, -0.04479438],
       [-0.27336687,  0.34549594, -0.11853147,  0.15316617],
       [ 0.50613236,  0.8698236 ,  0.83618736,  0.4850769 ]],
      dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'my_tensor/bias:0' shape=(4,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

If bb is a tensor inside a model or a tensor that the size of the input is fix this will not work

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3,), name="inputs")
b = keras.layers.Dense(4, name="my_tensor")(inputs)

a = tf.constant([[1,5,3]])
print('b:',b(a),'\n')
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable
```

i use feature_extractor to fix it:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(3,), name="inputs")
bb = keras.layers.Dense(4, name="my_tensor")(inputs)

feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    inputs=inputs,
    outputs=bb,
)

aa = tf.constant([[1,5,3]])
print('feature_extractor:',feature_extractor(aa),'\n')
```

Output:

```
feature_extractor: tf.Tensor([[-4.9181094  4.956725  -1.8055304  2.6975303]], shape=(1, 4), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the values from the tensor symbolic variable directly. Yo need to write a theano function to extract the value. Don't forget to choose theano as backend of Keras.

Check the notebook link to get some basic of theano variables and functions : [get tensor value in call function of own layers](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/craffel/theano-tutorial/blob/master/Theano%20Tutorial.ipynb#Functions)

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
print("y_true = " + str(y_true.eval()))
```

for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the output values of arbitrary layer keras tensors ("How can I print the values of Keras tensors?") it appears a different solution is required. To print the output of a single layer (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65288168/2585501):

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
layerIndex = 1
func = K.function([model.get_layer(index=0).input], model.get_layer(index=layerIndex).output)
layerOutput = func([input_data])  # input_data is a numpy array
print(layerOutput)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the keras API in TF2, you can do this with a keras Lambda layer. Doing so will prevent `tf.print` from getting called during model-building, but rather during actual training/inference:

```
activations_1 = ...
activations_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=123)(activations_1)
def print_act_2(act_2):
    tf.print("act_2", act_2)
    return act_2
activations_2 = layers.Lambda(print_act_2)(activations_2)
```