# how to see tensor value of a layer output in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, autoencoder, tf.keras

I have a Seq2Seq model. I am interested to print out the matrix value of the output of the encoder per iteration.

So for example as the dimension of the matrix in the `encoder` is `(?,20)` and the `epoch =5` and in each epoch, there are `10` iteration,
I would like to see `10` matrix of the dimension `(?,20)` per `epoch`.

I have gone to several links as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448029/debugging-keras-tensor-values) but it still does not print out the value matrix.
With this code as mentioned in the aboved link:

```
import keras.backend as K

k_value = K.print_tensor(encoded)
print(k_value)
```

I got:

```
Tensor("Print:0", shape=(?, 20), dtype=float32)
```

Is there any straightforward way of showing the tensor value of each layer in Keras?

**Update 1**

by trying this code: `K_value = K.eval(encoded)` it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float and shape [?,45,50]
     [[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,45,50], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: encoder_lstm/add_16/_25 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_460_encoder_lstm/add_16", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sgnbx/Downloads/projects/LSTM_autoencoder/justfun.py", line 121, in <module>
    k_value = K.eval(encoded)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 671, in eval
    return to_dense(x).eval(session=get_session())
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 680, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4951, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float and shape [?,45,50]
     [[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,45,50], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: encoder_lstm/add_16/_25 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_460_encoder_lstm/add_16", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'input', defined at:
  File "/home/sgnbx/Downloads/projects/LSTM_autoencoder/justfun.py", line 113, in <module>
    inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, EMBED_SIZE), name="input")
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 177, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 86, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 515, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1735, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4925, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1717, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype float and shape [?,45,50]
     [[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,45,50], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: encoder_lstm/add_16/_25 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_460_encoder_lstm/add_16", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7fd900525c50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sgnbx/anaconda3/envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 686, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You can get layer output in Keras whih return numpy values

Comment: @Anakin Thank you so much for following my question, Do you mind to give an example of how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Very simple way to print a tensor :

```
from keras import backend as K

k_value = K.eval(tensor)
print(k_value)
```

**UPDATE 1**

Create a callback to print at the end of each epoch :

```
class callback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, X_train):
        self.model = model
        self.x = X_train

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        inp = model.input  # input placeholder
        outputs = model.layers[N].output  # get output of N's layer
        functors = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], [outputs])
        layer_outs = functors([self.x, 1.])
        print('\r OUTPUT TENSOR : %s' % layer_outs)

        return

    def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        return
```

Call this function in your fit() method like that :

```
callbacks=[callback(model = model, X_train = X_train)])
```

Inspired from [Keras, How to get the output of each layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711190/keras-how-to-get-the-output-of-each-layer)

Hope this will finally help you !

Comment: thanks for your answer. but which library is tensor here? this code written in KERAS

Comment: Can you also include the import libraries, please? if you mean the tensor array that I have I have already tried this(a variation of this) but it raises error, if you mean tensor= my tensor array I can update the question with the error which raises.

Comment: Thank you gaian for following, I did not mean that I have the restriction for using only Keras. the thing is that this updated answer and also the previous one raises anerror, I update my question with the error

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's look like your tensor is empty. If you try to print this tensor : tensor = K.ones(shape=(3, 4, 5)) with my code, is it working ?

Comment: I have my final output printed, So it means this code is working fine. I need the output in each iteration.

Comment: I think I got what is happening here, I am trying to print out before fitting the model in the process of building the model. on the other hand, if I print it out after fitting the model is it is getting the same error as above. In case I create a model out of my encoder and use that model with the code above again the same error!

Comment: I think you need to create a callback that will print the tensor a each epoch, and give to it the tensor you want

Comment: Thanks again, do you have any similar example for calling the callbacks on the tensor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193788/discussion-between-thibault-bacqueyrisses-and-sariii).