# How to print Keras tensor values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to print the state values of LSTM layer.

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = self.model.layers[1].output
        print(state_h)
        print(state_c)
```

It is printing something like this

```
32/32 - 0s - loss: 39.6719 - accuracy: 0.2420
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='lstm_5/PartitionedCall:3', description="created by layer 'lstm_5'")
Epoch 5/20000
32/32 - 0s - loss: 39.6549 - accuracy: 0.2420
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='lstm_5/PartitionedCall:3', description="created by layer 'lstm_5'")
```

How to print the real values of the tensor ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print the values of Keras tensors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448029/how-can-i-print-the-values-of-keras-tensors)

Comment: That post didn't helped. After making run_eagerly = True 
print(y_true)      - Doesn't work
tf.print(y_true)   - Doesn't work
K.print_tensor(y_true) - Doesn't work

If I try to use K.eval, I am getting this error
'''
'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
'''

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to feed some data to your `LSTM` layer inside your `Callback` function in order to see some real values:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def __init__(self, data, sample_size):
        self.data = data
        self.sample_size = sample_size
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = lstm_layer(self.data[:self.sample_size])
        tf.print('state_h --> ', state_h)
        tf.print('state_c --> ', state_c)


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((5, 10))
x, _, _ = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())

lstm_layer = model.layers[1]
x_train = tf.random.normal((10, 5, 10))
x_test = tf.random.normal((10, 5, 10))
model.fit(x_train, tf.random.uniform((10, 1), maxval=2), epochs=2, callbacks=[CustomCallback(x_test, 1)], batch_size=2)
```

```
Epoch 1/2
5/5 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: 12.2492
state_h -->  [[-0.157256633 -0.0619691685 0.102620631 ... 0.0852451548 -0.0657120794 -0.201934695]]
state_c -->  [[-0.316935241 -0.157902092 0.184583426 ... 0.196862131 -0.134880155 -0.467693359]]
Epoch 2/2
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step - loss: 11.8095
state_h -->  [[-0.15817374 -0.0611076616 0.103141323 ... 0.0845508352 -0.0648964494 -0.201082334]]
state_c -->  [[-0.319411457 -0.156104326 0.186640084 ... 0.194445729 -0.13365829 -0.464410305]]
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f9baadc8b90>
```

Notice that I created a `x_test` tensor, but you can also just feed `x_train` to your callback. The `lstm_layer` holds the current weights based on your training progress. You can verify this by printing the layer weights in your `Callback` function: `tf.print(lstm_layer.get_weights())`.