# How to print the value of the keras Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is part of the network structure:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(time_step, dim))
lstm_out = LSTM(5, return_sequen`enter code here`ces=True)(inputs)
print(lstm_out)
attention_mul = attention_3d_block(inputs)
attention_flatten = Flatten()(attention_mul)
output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(attention_flatten)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
Adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
```

I want to print the result value of the LSTM layer: `print(lstm_out)`

but it gives me:

```
KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3, 5), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), 
name='lstm/PartitionedCall:1', description="created by layer 'lstm'")
```

I just want to get the `value`. How to do it?

Comment: You have to feed actual data to your `LSTM` layer to see any "values"

Comment: model.fit(data_x, data_y, epochs=10)  data_x is my actual data ,I want to debug it in my training

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802548/how-to-print-keras-tensor-values/69806679#69806679

Comment: That's so helpful for me！！ Thank you very much