# Building Custom Loss and accessing data from y_pred

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function, model-fitting

I'm working on a regression problem to reconstruct the information to mitigate crosstalk effects from neighbors' sensors, and I want to change the loss function to evaluate the standard deviation in an intermediate step inside my custom loss function.

Here is the code that I want to implement:

My `y_pred` as shape `(nEvents, 100)`

I found many examples to create my loss function as below:

```
import backend as K
def my_loss_func1(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_actual) + K.square(layer), axis=-1)
```

But in those examples, I didn't find how to access data inside the `y_pred` (TensorFlow variable). In all examples, it just uses a function from the backend to evaluate the loss passing `y_pred`, `y_true` as a parameter.

What I need to do is:

```
def my_loss_func2(y_true, y_pred):
    samples = y_pred( <HOW DO TO GET THE VALUES?> )
    cells   = int(samples.shape[1]/4)

    AmpRec  = np.tensordot(samples.reshape(samples.shape[0], signals, nSamp),ai, axes=(2,0))
    TimeRec = np.tensordot(samples.reshape(samples.shape[0], signals, nSamp),ai, axes=(2,0))/AmpRec
    
    return K.std(TimeRec)
```

I want to improve and update my model to adjust weights, taking into account the optimal_filter output concerning the `timeRec` spread (std).

Has anybody evaluated the loss function accessing `y_pred` like I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

---

Today, a few days after...

I found a solution, reading the post [how to print Keras tensors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322530/15013317).

There exist some methods to manipulate a tensor, like:

```
K.eva(tensor)
K.print_tensor(tensor)
...
```

But to enable those, it's necessary to add *run_eagerly* on the model compile method:

```
model.compile(..., run_eagerly = True)
```

After this single step, you can access tensor information to manipulate as you need.