# How to Solve <class 'int'> Error in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bayesian, pymc3

I want to do a Bayesian analysis in python with a custom defined likelihood function. Below is my code.

I get the <class 'int'> error when I run the code. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from gurobipy import quicksum
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1, 125, 100), columns= ['Surface'])

def logp(Surface):
   return (-c*quicksum(j**b for i in range(0,len(df)) for j in 
range(1,Surface[i].astype(int))))

with pm.Model() as model_g:
   c = pm.Uniform('c', lower=0, upper=1)
   b = pm.Uniform('b', lower=0, upper=1)
   y = pm.DensityDist('y', logp, observed={'Surface':df['Surface']})
   trace_g = pm.sample(100, tune=100)  

az.plot_trace(trace_g, var_names=['c']);
```

Comment: it would help if you showed the stack trace. what line is the error occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a TensorVariable as an int. Range expects an int. We don't know what df or 'Surface' look like.

See this answer:
[How to get value from a theano tensor variable backed by a shared variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361377/how-to-get-value-from-a-theano-tensor-variable-backed-by-a-shared-variable)

Comment: I could not solve the problem using the link. Could you please give me more hints? I included df['Surface'] in my question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, then please post all of the code. I'll have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I updated the code in my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Could you explain what your probability distribution function does?

Comment: Actually, I could fix the issue by replacing "quicksum" with "sum+".  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you've solved the problem! Sum+? Do you know about the Math module? https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api/math.html It has the "sum" function which is intended to be used with Theano variables.

Comment: Working with sum+ was easier than the sum function as in each loop I wanted to calculate j**b for j in an uncertain range.